# How to check if statements match (Zip functions)

Tags: python, authentication

So I am currently working on a little project for a log in feature at school. I have attempted to store usernames and passwords in lists and check them using a [0:1] process. Is there a way that  I can check to see if user input matches zipped lists in a selected part? 
Sorry if this is super simple I am quite new to coding.

Code:

```
Profile = ['jc1', 'jc2', 'jc3', 'jc4', 'jc5']
Passwords = ['123','213','312','321','231']

Prof = zip(Profile[0:1],Passwords[0:1])

A = list(Prof)

JK = input('Please enter your username: ')

DK = input('Please enter your password: ')

Entry = zip(JK,DK)

B = list(Entry)

if B == A:

print('Welcome User: jc1')

print(A)
```

Comment: All you're doing can be expressed as `JK == Profile[0] and DK == Passwords[0]`. You're only checking the first entry… You probably want to check whether the entered values match *any* combination in the profile/password list…!?

Comment: Why don't you use `dictionary` to store the `profileName-password` combination instead of list ?

Comment: I'm only checking the first entry since I am unsure how to get `zip` to even begin working. I will try using `dictionary` and see if I can get it working.

Comment: @PrashantKumar for `dictionary` how would I make passwords correlate to each user? Again sorry for lack of knowledge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can store the `profileName` and `password` combination in `dictionary` and check with user input.

```
profile_password_mapping = ['jc1':'123', 'jc2':'213', 'jc3':'312', 'jc4':'321', 'jc5':'231']

profileName = input('Please enter your username: ')

profilePassword = input('Please enter your password: ')

if profileName in profile_password_mapping.keys() and  profile_password_mapping[profileName] == profilePassword:

    print('Welcome User: {0}'.format(profileName))
else:
    print("User does not exist or the password is wrong.")
```

Comment: `[...:..., ...]`…!?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use index value of both the list for profile to password matching

```
Profile = ['jc1', 'jc2', 'jc3', 'jc4', 'jc5']
Passwords = ['123','213','312','321','231']

JK = raw_input('Please enter your username: ')
if JK in Profiles:
    DK = raw_input('Please enter your password: ')
    if DK in Passwords and Profiles.index(JK) == Password.index(DK):
        print "Welcome user %s"%(JK)
    else:
        print "Incorrect Password"
else:
    print "User %s not in Profile list"%(JK)
```

FOr now you can live with list, but it will be better if you learn about `dictionaries` and try to implement the same via dictionary